# Modifying CSS file

Tags: html, css

I am trying to reach a `div` class/id traversing through a parent class, the HTML that I am working on looks like this:

```
<div id="content" class="content xcShortcuts associate">
<div id="callbackScreen" class="callback FLY_MENU active" tabindex="-1">
     <div id="callbackContainer" class="hidden">
<div id="callbackContent" class="3D active"><div class="cbLayout actions">
<div class="cbDilg"><div id="3DOT" class="cbBody">
```

I need to reach the `class="cbBody`".

What I am doing is:

```
#content .callbackScreen .callbackContainer .callbackContent .cbLayout.actions {
right: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 30%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
}
```

But somehow it's not working, any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since an ID must be unique in a document and assuming all div's will close after all are opened, **#callbackContainer .cbBody** should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ids are accessed using `#` and classes are accessed using `.`
You have mixed those. `callbackScreen`, `callbackContainer` and `callbackContent` are ids and need to be accessed using #

This needs to be the hierarchy

```
#content #callbackScreen #callbackContainer #callbackContent .cbLayout.actions .cbDilg .cbBody{
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Note: This hierarchy in the question for applying css is too much and can be reduced if [css specificy concepts](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) are used properly

Comment: The above solution is correct. Please try to reduce the hierarchy as much as possible

Comment: Yes, hierarchy is too much. But it is what OP has asked for. `trying to reach a div class/id traversing through a parent class`. So have given the full hierarchy. From the OP's post, it can't be made as to which classes can be removed/kept. However, will give a note to in the answer stating the same

Comment: Can you do inspect element for that div and see that the css for that particular div is showing up? Also, please check for spelling mistakes etc in your code as well

Comment: @Sunil is there any way we can use "class="callback FLY_MENU active" instead of callbackscreen? I am pretty new to this.

Comment: Yes. You need to replace #callbackScreen with `.callback.FLY_MENU.active`. I will advise you to read more about how and when to use ids and classes in css for better understanding